# Why is my jQuery dialog using Deferred not waiting for user selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have the following function that creates a dialog and is using jQuery deferred to wait for the user response:

```
function myPageUnsaved() {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $('<div></div>')
    .html('You have unsaved changes. Leave this page and lose your changes?')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Confirmation',
        buttons: {
            "No": function () {
                defer.resolve("false");
                $(this).dialog("close");
             },
             "Yes": function () {
                defer.resolve("true");
                $(this).dialog("close");
             }
        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
        }
    });
    return defer.promise();
}
```

I call the function within the js below:

```
// function to check for user changes prior to navigating to a new page
function checkPageChange() {
    if (pageChanges == true) {
        myPageUnsaved().then(function (answer) {
            // if user answered no, stay on the page
            if(answer == 'false') {
                return false;
            // else the user answered yes, so leave the page
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });

    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am running jQuery 1.11.

The dialog is presented to the user, but immediately is removed.  What am I missing?

Comment: I think first you need to upgrade your jQuery version with the latest version available here https://jquery.com/download/

Comment: I can look into that, but Deferred was supported in 1.11.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern used seems correct, my initial answer was incorrect. .promise is a method of deferred and all member methods can be seen here. http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Example of the code provided by original poster which seems to work in jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/n7ewqfc0/

---

**Initial answer - incorrect asumptions**

Have you tried just returning the `defer` as opposed to defer.promise(); That doesn't seem right to me.

Looking at the spec for `Deferred` there is no reference to the `promise` method.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/

Obviously I have hugely simplified your code to provide a resolving Promise but the principles are the same. You must return the promise object i.e. `Deferred` to be able to use the promise based callbacks `.then` etc.

```
function myPageUnsaved() {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        defer.resolve('hey back from inside the promise')
    }, 2000)
    return defer;
}

var p = myPageUnsaved()
p.then(function(response){
  console.log(response)
})
```

Comment: I see from creating a fiddle `defer.promise` works the same as `defer`. I should have checked first. Can you put the whole thin in a jsfiddle?

Comment: A quick attempt to replicate your code and it does seem to work. https://jsfiddle.net/n7ewqfc0/

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I am glad it worked for you.  So something else in my code may be keeping it from holding up.  When I debug it, it refuses to hold.

Comment: Yeah sounds like an issue within the full code. Share the jsfiddle if you can, there must be a good reason. if you can't put a breakpoint in with devtools, try the `debugger` keyword at the point you want to to analyse.